# XML Element Value Writing as A String Giving IO Error C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to hold a log XML file. Code sample at below.

```
private class LogFunctionInfo
{
    private string logName;
    public string FunctionName;
    public Type FunctionClassType;
    public int Displayed;
    public int Offset;
    public int Multiplier;

    public string LogName { get => logName; set => logName = value; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return logName;
    }
}

private LogFunctionInfo[] LoggingFunctions = {bla bla bla};
loggingNames = LoggingFunctions.Select(a => a.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Clone().ToString()).ToArray();
do
{
    try
    {
        XElement xml = XElement.Load(xmlLogFileName);

        for (int LineCounter = 0; LineCounter < LogBufferCounter; LineCounter++)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            for (int count = 0; count < LogNumber; count++)
            {
                //dictionary.Add("Value" + count, LogBuffer[LineCounter][count]); // If I use this, its working like a charm.
                dictionary.Add(loggingNames[count], LogBuffer[LineCounter][count]); // If I use this, giving XmlException at System.Xml.dll error
                minute = count == 22 ? LogBuffer[LineCounter][count] : minute;
            }
            xml.Add(new XElement("GraphValues",
                new XAttribute("Time", minute),
                new XElement("Values",
                dictionary.Select(element => new XElement(element.Key, element.Value)))));
            dictionary.Clear();
        }
        xml.Save(xmlLogFileName);
        Flushed = true;
        LogBufferCounter = 0;
    }
    catch
    {
        Flushed = false;
    }
} while (Flushed == false);
```

Its giving System.Xml.Exception when I use a string array that values are coming from an object. What is the difference between fill by hand("Value" + count) with using an filled array?

Comment: so the *difference* here is `"Value" + count` vs `loggingNames[count]`? what is the *actual value* of `loggingNames[count]` when you run this? it sounds like at least one of the `loggingNames` values simply can't be represented as an xml attribute, but to know *why*, it would help to know what the *values* are

Comment: and exception details (message, innerexception)?

Comment: Are you trying to add one xml node or multiple nodes?  If only one node then use string.Join(",", array[])

Answer (score 0):

I removed the try catch block for to take details of exception.
Thanks for asking details to @Cee McSharpface and @Marc Gravell♦

It was about my array you guys are right.
In my array one string is starting with number and it was giving XML error.

Problem solved thanks again.